# How to sort dataframe by sum of fields grouped by multiple columns

Tags: pandas

I have dataframe

```
city      device  sessions_count
-----------------------------
New York  desktop   10
New York  mobile    9
Chicago   desktop   6
Detroit   desktop   16
Detroit   mobile    7
```

I need to build stacked bar-chart, where bar represents city and it is devided by device type. I have managed to make it only for first rows this way

```
city_device = df.groupby(['city', 'device'])['sessions_count'].agg([np.sum]);
city_device.unstack().head(n=5).iplot(kind='bar', barmode='stack')
```

But I need to show only most visited cities (sort by sum of sessions_count by every city). How can I do that?

Comment: do you want a split between mobile/desktop for the mosted visited count or not?

Comment: @StevenG yes I need to keep that split but sort by sum of mobile and desktop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need helper column `tmp` for sorting, for replace `NaN`s with `0` add `fill_value=0` parameter to [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
a = df.groupby(['city', 'device'])['sessions_count'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
a = a.assign(tmp=a.sum(axis=1)).sort_values('tmp', ascending=False).drop('tmp', 1).head(5)
print (a)
device    desktop  mobile
city                     
New York       10       9
Detroit        16       1
Chicago         6       0
```

Comment: Hmm, something is wrong with the data? Detroit mobile should be 7?

Comment: the dataframe provided had an error in it, it was modile instead of mobile

Answer (score 2):

The approach I can think about is using a `pivot_table` with margins to have the totals by city keeping the values by device. Then you can sort by the margin, delete the margins and then plot the stacked barplot.

Here's the code:

```
# Creates the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'city':['New York', 'New York', 'Chicago', 'Detroit', 'Detroit'],
    'device': ['desktop', 'mobile', 'desktop', 'desktop', 'mobile'],
    'session_count': [10, 9, 6, 16, 7]
})

# Creates a pivot table with margins named 'All'
# Sorts by 'All' column
# Drops the margins
# Plots the stacked barplot
df.pivot_table(columns='device',
               index='city',
               values='session_count',
               aggfunc=sum,
               margins=True).\
    sort_values(by='All', ascending=False).\
    drop('All').drop('All', axis=1).\
    plot.bar(stacked=True);
```

And here's the result:

[image: Result chart]

The 'step by step' data construction is the following:

```
# Creates the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'city':['New York', 'New York', 'Chicago', 'Detroit', 'Detroit'],
    'device': ['desktop', 'mobile', 'desktop', 'desktop', 'mobile'],
    'session_count': [10, 9, 6, 16, 7]
})

print(df)

#        city   device  session_count
# 0  New York  desktop             10
# 1  New York   mobile              9
# 2   Chicago  desktop              6
# 3   Detroit  desktop             16
# 4   Detroit   mobile              7

print(df.pivot_table(columns='device',
               index='city',
               values='session_count',
               aggfunc=sum,
               margins=True))

# device    desktop  mobile   All
# city                           
# Chicago       6.0     NaN   6.0
# Detroit      16.0     7.0  23.0
# New York     10.0     9.0  19.0
# All          32.0    16.0  48.0

print(df.pivot_table(columns='device',
               index='city',
               values='session_count',
               aggfunc=sum,
               margins=True).\
    sort_values(by='All', ascending=False))

# device    desktop  mobile   All
# city                           
# All          32.0    16.0  48.0
# Detroit      16.0     7.0  23.0
# New York     10.0     9.0  19.0
# Chicago       6.0     NaN   6.0


print(df.pivot_table(columns='device',
               index='city',
               values='session_count',
               aggfunc=sum,
               margins=True).\
    sort_values(by='All', ascending=False).\
    drop('All').drop('All', axis=1))

# device    desktop  mobile
# city                     
# Detroit      16.0     7.0
# New York     10.0     9.0
# Chicago       6.0     NaN
```

Then all you have to do is plot the stacked barplot.

Answer (score 1):

just change the `tail()` value for larger set.:

```
grouped_all = df.groupby(['city']).sum()
city = grouped_all.sort_values('sessions_count').tail(2).index
grouped_split = df[df.city.isin(city)].groupby(['city', 'device']).sum()

                  sessions_count
city     device                 
Detroit  desktop              16
         mobile                7
New York desktop              10
         mobile                9
```

now plot

```
grouped_split.unstack(level=0).plot.bar(stacked=True)
```